# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Long; on iterating through values from the db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am trying to fetch the last data in a table using hibernate as shown in the following snippets

```
query.setMaxResults(1);
         List<Long[]> rows =  query.list();
         System.out.println("current row>>>>>>  " +rows.toString());

          for (Long[] row: rows) {
                System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
                long val = (Long) row[6];
                System.out.println("current file: " + val);
            }

          }catch(Exception ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
```

this is my query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select f.currentfile.id from File f order by f.id DESC");
```

I am having the error at this line of the code

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Long;
for (Long[] row: rows) {
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Ljava.lang.Long means List of java.lang.Long

Comment: what is your query, what you are returning

Comment: query has just been added

Comment: According to your querry (assuming that the id of a file is a long) you'll get a List<Long> and not a List<Long[]>. Try:  _List<Long> rows =  query.list();_

Comment: also you have set max result to 1,  it will return single `Long`

Comment: I have tried that, but it fails at this line long val = (Long) row[6];

Comment: still not getting result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `query.setMaxResults(1);`

otherwise u will get single result

try this

**Edited**

```
     List<Long> rows =  query.list();
     System.out.println("current row>>>>>>  " +rows.toString());

      for (Long val: rows) {
            System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
            System.out.println("current file: " + val);
      }
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Long to Long[] Change type row to Long

Answer (score 3):

Your Query returns `List<Long>` and you are assigning `List<Long[]>`

```
Long is java.lang.Long

Long[] is [Ljava.lang.Long
```

Comment: List<Long> rows =  query.list();

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Long to Long[] Change type row to Long

Comment: you also need to change row to Long in for loop